# Design Question: Behavior in different contexts

Tags: c#, sql, design-patterns

I have a general question: What should be done when an object's behavior should change according to context? (Please note that this is regarding SQL and not C#, but I could really use ideas here)

For example, the Search class, let's call it "SearchObject". This SearchObject gets a search term and returns 5 results from Google. It does this and this only.
Now I have a new requirement: if the object is called from a certain context, it appends results from another search engine. For example, if I call a search from a web page, this object should bring 10 results: first 5 from Google, last 5 from Bing. If it's called from a console application, it should bring the last 5 results from AltaVista.

How do I keep this object's behavior according to the OOP principles AND get the desired result?
(The implementation will be in SQL, so I can't use the design patterns I know in C#...)

Thanks!

Comment: There is such a thing as Object Oriented SQL Programming?  Also, why are you trying to do this in SQL when you are making calls to the DB from a web application and a console application.  The web/console app seem like the logical place to handle this type of thing...

Comment: Is there a good reason to prevent the client from deciding what kind of search it wants to do?  I like the parameter examples already covered by others because it relieves the database of needing to know about specific client contexts.  I'd sooner put a service to force calling correct versions of sprocs between my application the DB than teach the DB too much about the application.  Teaching the database too much about its clients tends to cause maintainability and/or predictability issues sooner than later.

Is there a reason you can't/shouldn't approach it from that angle?

Comment: @Pete M, the reason I can't do that is that the DB writes the result set to a table, because we have a limited "search term vocabulary". This sort of mechanism helps us avoid from performing calculations over and over again.

Comment: I don't understand how that would prevent an application from passing an argument denoting which flavor of search the database should execute.  I'm asking if there's a reason why the application shouldn't be allowed to tell the database what search(s) to do as opposed to the database deciding on it's own based on some knowledge of who is calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously its much more common to do this in elsewhere, but if you're keeping the behavioral logic in SQL you could do one of the following

**Use a parameter**

just pass something to the procedure. For Example

```
Create Proc sp_Search (@Search varchar(500), @behavior int)
AS

if @behavior = 1
 ...
if @behavior = 2
...
```

However this requires your applications to have knowledge of this parameter, and this may not be what you're looking to do.

**Use something about the session**

You could also use information about the session. For example [`APP_NAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx)

```
Create Proc sp_Search (@Search varchar(500))
AS

if APP_NAME()=  'Application A'
 ...
if APP_NAME()= 'Application B'
...
```

**Use a specific user**

Another option is to dole out the user names to the context they're going to use and then use [`CURRENT_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx)

Create Proc sp_Search (@Search varchar(500))
    AS

```
if CURRENT_USER()=  'ConsoleCreds'
 ...
if  CURRENT_USER()= 'WebCreds'
...
```

Honestly I would rather allow any behavior by any application (The Mechanism) and then configure the policy for each application, rather than tying the Mechanism and Policy together (as above)

Comment: +1 for the various approaches.  I'd strongly urge the parameter approach unless there's a good business/technical reason to use the other two.

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing this in C#, I would do something along the lines of  having a context object that is provided to the SearchObject and produces the necessary parameters.

To implement a similar idea in SQL, you would have a Context table with ContextName,SearchEngine,TopX, etc.   and join that to a Searches table (assuming you're doing some sort of caching here) to get your results.

Something like..

```
SELECT * FROM Searches s  
  INNER JOIN Context ct ON sr.search = ct.search
  WHERE sr.rank <= ct.TopX
  AND   (searchterm = ... etc )
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT s.*, rank() OVER (partition by search_term,search order by rank asc), FROM Searches s ORDER BY rank ASC)
  INNER JOIN Context ct ON sr.search = ct.search
  WHERE sr.rank <= ct.BottomX
  AND   (searchterm = ... etc )
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple algorithms/techniques/approaches to accomplish a goal, and want to make a runtime decision of which technique to use, you should consider using the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

Strategy is frequently paired with [FactoryMethod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.  Basically, call the FactoryMethod, passing whatever data is necessary for it to make a decision.  It encapsulates the actual decision-making logic, and returns an instance of the appropriate strategy object.